# Defining a variable within a Genshi template

Tags: python, templates, python-2.x, genshi

How can I define a variable within a Genshi template for reuse?

Let's say i have two nested for loops:

```
<div py:for="i in xrange(5)>
    <div py:for=j in xrange(10)>
        <!-- do something with "i * j" -->
        <!-- do something else with "i * j" -->
        <!-- do yet another thing with "i * j" -->
    </div>
</div>
```

As indicated in the comments, I want to do a simple calculation with the two loop variables and then do something with the reslt (e.g. insert it into the template).

If possible I want to reuse the result of the calculation instead of calculating it multiple times (because the calculation might be a little bit more difficult than in the example, and also I don't want to copy the code for the calculation if I can just use a variable).

I know that one shouldn't do too many calculations in a template, but this is just an example. My goal is reusing stuff. Also I know that there is the `def`tag for defining macros, but I think these just create text rather than a variable, so I can't use it for example in an `if`tag for condition checking.

Is there a way to have a Python tag in a Genshi template just for simple Python expressions without having to output something?

Answer (score 1):

Starting form the end:
Is there a way to have a Python tag in a Genshi template just for simple Python expressions without having to output something?

Yes, you can use the following tag:

```
<?python ... ?>
```

For example:

```
   <?python
            if 'condition':
                var = 'controls'
            else:
                var = 'controls row-fluid'
          ?>
```

and then:

```
<-- now class='controls' if 'condition' is true else class='controls row-fluid' -->
<div class="$var">
       <-- put something inside -->
</div>
```

I hope it helps, if something is unclear or 'weird' please comment.